# OpenAPI- dynamiclly adding array properties

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, api-platform.com

I am using **OpenApi** *(Swagger)* within API Platform and I want to achieve the following result.. Define dynamic array adding params like:

[image]

My definition so far:

```
new Get(
        uriTemplate: '/v1/examples/query',
        openapi: new Model\Operation(
            summary: 'Query example',
            parameters: [
                [
                    'name' => 'array',
                    'in' => 'query',
                    'type' => 'array',
                    'items' => [
                        'properties' => [
                            'type' => 'string'
                        ]
                    ],
                    'description' => 'array'
                ],
                [
                    'name' => 'property',
                    'in' => 'query',
                    'type' => 'string',
                    'description' => 'string'
                ]
            ]
        ),
        name: 'query_endpoint'
    ),
```

And the result is:

[image]

Can someone please help? I was trying to find it in the docs, but adding **properties** inside **items** key did not work..

Comment: If you replace `['properties' => ['type' => 'string'] ]` with `['type' => 'string']`, does this resolve the issue?

Comment: It was the first thing I tried, the result is the same. :/ @Helen